# How to know Cobalt state at starboard layer?

Tags: cobalt

How can we get cobalt page loading state from starboard ?
We want to exit Cobalt application If network error message received in star board during app launch So for this we want to know Cobalt app state in starboard.

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt will call SbSystemRaisePlatformError() if it encounters an unrecoverable connection error (the call is made here: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/browser/h5vcc_url_handler.cc#104 ).  You can implement on your platform to react appropriately, will that work for you?

In general, we do not support having the Starboard layer depend on the Cobalt layer in any way (otherwise there would be a cyclical dependency).

Comment: Hi Andrew Thanks for your reply.   
 I am already handling SbSystemRaisePlatformError call but I wanted to differentiate this call  based on below cases:  
1) When I launch there is a network error   
2) Network error occurs after Cobalt successfully launched YouTube page  and while navigating the UI.  
  
In both the cases above, I am  getting SbSystemRaisePlatformError call to  starboard but I am  not able to differentiate the error call was for case (1) or (2).  I was thinking that  If I can query the COBALT’s state then  I can differentiate . Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: `SbSystemRaisePlatformError()` will only be called if Cobalt fails to load a web app. In other words, it's only called during navigation (including initial navigation on startup). YouTube is a single-paged app, so it never performs navigation once it's successfully loaded, so the case #2 should be impossible. Please file a bug against Cobalt if you see this happening.